# Unit testing set innerexception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a method that in a particular scenario should throw an exception which has an inner exception:

```
mockInvoiceRepository.Setup(x => x.PersistInvoice(invoice, false)).Throws(new Exception());
```

That line of code is fine except I need to set the innerexception for the new exception that is thrown. I can't do this though because it is a readonly property and also can't mock it because it's not virtual.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would this work?  Here I am using the [overloaded constructor of Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf.aspx) that takes a string message (which you don't seem to care about) and an inner exception.

```
var innerException = new ExpectedInnerException();
mockInvoiceRepository.Setup(x => x.PersistInvoice(invoice, false))
                     .Throws(new Exception("", innerException));
```

Comment: Oh true, I didn't realise you could set it through constructor.